# Unexpected indent error in Python even though there's no indents

Tags: python

When I run this code, I get an Unexpected indent Error but there are no indents where it says there are. I am using python 64-bit and Python 3. I have tried unindenting all the code and reindenting it but I get the same error. I am trying to create a GUI where a user can sign up and log in.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import json
import hashlib
import uuid
from tkinter import messagebox
filename = ("username.json")
filename2 = ("password.json")

def hash_password(password):
    # uuid is used to generate a random number
    salt = uuid.uuid4().hex
    return hashlib.sha256(salt.encode() + password.encode()).hexdigest() + ':' + salt

def check_password(hashed_password, user_password):
    password, salt = hashed_password.split(':')
    return password == hashlib.sha256(salt.encode() + user_password.encode()).hexdigest()

def sign_up():
    adduser = (e3.get())
    addpassword = (e4.get())

    try:
        hashed_password = hash_password(addpassword)
        with open (filename, "w") as f_obj:
            json.dump(adduser, f_obj)

        with open (filename2, "w") as f:
            json.dump(hashed_password, f)
        #print("Signed up")
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "You have succesfully signed up!")

def log_in():
    try:
        with open (filename) as f_obj:
        data = json.load(f_obj)
    except FileNotFoundError :
        usernameguess = (e1.get())
        passwordguess = (e2.get())
        user_attempt = usernameguess
        pwd_attempt = passwordguess
        with open (filename) as f_obj:
            username = json.load(f_obj)
        if username == user_attempt:
            with open (filename2) as f:
            password = json.load(f)
            if check_password(password, pwd_attempt):
                print("You're into your account")
            else:
                print("Incorrect password")
        else:
            print("Incorrect username")


master = Tk()

master.geometry("390x220")
master.iconbitmap('favicon.ico')
master.title("Account Manager : Log In | Sign Up")
Label(master, text="Welcome to the Account Manager \n Sign up or Log in \n Note: Your password is protected by hash encryption").grid(row=0, column=1)
Label(master, text="Log In").grid(row=1, column=1)
Label(master, text="Username").grid(row=2)
Label(master, text="Password").grid(row=3)

Label(master, text="Sign Up").grid(row=5, column=1)
Label(master, text="Username").grid(row=6)
Label(master, text="Password").grid(row=7)


e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)
e3 = Entry(master)
e4 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=2, column=1)
e2.grid(row=3, column=1)
e3.grid(row=6, column=1)
e4.grid(row=7, column=1)


Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Sign Up', command=sign_up).grid(row=8, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Log In', command=log_in).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)


mainloop( )
```

Comment: can you post your error traceback?

Comment: Please post the full error message, starting from the Traceback line. I can't see any unexpected indents there, but there a couple of `with` statements that should have indents for the code that's supposed to be in the `with` block.

Comment: I'll bet you're getting an "Unexpected *un*indent" error.

Comment: BTW, if you really want to do this properly you should use a better password hashing function. The standard library (since Python 3.4) has pbkdf2, and since 3.6 has scrypt. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#key-derivation

Comment: @B.Sommer you should accept the answer if your problem is solved: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

The error is not in same but in previous line!

In function `sign_up()` (the function before `log_in()` function), there is `try` but not `except:`

```
def sign_up():
    adduser = (e3.get())
    addpassword = (e4.get())

    try:
        hashed_password = hash_password(addpassword)
        with open (filename, "w") as f_obj:
            json.dump(adduser, f_obj)

        with open (filename2, "w") as f:
            json.dump(hashed_password, f)
        #print("Signed up")
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "You have succesfully signed up!")

def log_in():
    try:
        with open (filename) as f_obj:
        ...
```

Python is expecting an indented `except:` statement. Hence, the error.

Other truely indent errors also exist in this code, which will become apparent once this error is corrected.

Maybe Python should give a `"missing except" error` rather than `"indent" error`.